# How to conditionally select one of two methods to receive same block

Tags: ruby

Im trying to change the process of an code dependent on an variable `req` how you can see here:

```
@res = @conn.post do |request| if req == 'post'
@res = @conn.get do |request| if req == 'get'
```

The problem is that this seems to raise an error:

```
stack.rb:89: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
user2.send_csr
```

My question is, what do i have to change to avoid this problem? If you need more information about my code:

```
def send(req,ww,text1=nil,text2=nil)
@conn = Faraday.new 'https://zombo.de/rest', :ssl => {:verify => false}
@conn.basic_auth(@username,@password)
@res = @conn.post do |request| if req == 'post'
@res = @conn.get do |request| if req == 'get'
 request.url ww
 request.headers['Content-Type'] = text1 unless text1 == nil
 request.body = text2 unless text2 == nil
end
puts @res.body
end

def send_csr
  send('post','csr','text/plain',"#{File.read(@csr[0..-5])}")
end

user2.send_csr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post-fix `if` cannot be placed as you have it, because technically that is in the middle of the block that you want to pass to the get or post.

You could do this:

```
@res = @conn.get do |request| 
 request.url ww
 request.headers['Content-Type'] = text1 unless text1 == nil
 request.body = text2 unless text2 == nil
end if req == 'get'
```

but that would require you to repeat the code block for each case. Also, I'd recommend against post-fixing conditionals after a long block, it is difficult to spot them when reading the code later.

So this syntax, using `send` might work best for you (it works because your string matches the method name)

```
@conn.send(req) do |request| 
 request.url ww
 request.headers['Content-Type'] = text1 unless text1 == nil
 request.body = text2 unless text2 == nil
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What if you extend your code a bit? Add some formating and change what goes into to blocks?

```
def send(req, ww, text1=nil, text2=nil)
  @conn = Faraday.new 'https://zombo.de/rest', :ssl => {:verify => false}

  @conn.basic_auth(@username,@password)

  @res = @conn.post { |request| handle_request(request) } if req == 'post'
  @res = @conn.get { |request| handle_request(request) } if req == 'get'

  @res.body
end

def handle_request request
  request.url ww
  request.headers['Content-Type'] = text1 unless text1 == nil
  request.body = text2 unless text2 == nil
  request
end

def send_csr
  send('post','csr','text/plain',"#{File.read(@csr[0..-5])}")
end

user2.send_csr
```

Comment: Its a really long solution

Comment: You can move the code that goes to #post and #get to some other function. Like #handle_request in my case - as shown above. That could be shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Faraday's `post` and `get` methods call `run_request`:

```
run_request(method, url, body, headers)
```

You could do the same:

```
def send(req, ww, text1=nil, text2=nil)
  @conn = Faraday.new 'https://zombo.de/rest', :ssl => {:verify => false}
  @conn.basic_auth(@username, @password)
  headers = text1 && {'Content-Type' => text1 }
  @res = @conn.run_request(req.to_sym, ww, text2, headers)
  puts @res.body
end
```

I'm passing `req.to_sym` because `run_request` expects a symbol (`:post` instead of `"post"`) and instead of setting `url`, `body` and `headers` in the block, I'm passing them, too.

Maybe you should rename some of your variables and replace instance variables by local ones:

```
def send(method, url, content_type=nil, body=nil)
  conn = Faraday.new 'https://zombo.de/rest', :ssl => {:verify => false}
  conn.basic_auth(@username, @password)
  headers = content_type && {'Content-Type' => content_type }
  res = conn.run_request(method.to_sym, url, body, headers)
  puts res.body
end
```